# Quad-rotor 1-D Linear Control Simulation with MATLAB

Tags: quadcopter, control

I was Performing Programming Assignment with MATLAB for Quad Thrust and Height for an Introductory Course. The control input for a PD controller was According to the Equation

u = mass*(diff(s_des, 2) + Kp*e + Kv*diff(e) + gravity)

where:

1. diff(s_des, 2) is the second diff. of the Desired Height which is 1 meter.
2. Kp & Kv are the Proportional and Derivative Gains which Require Tuning.
3. The Term "e" is the Position Error and diff(e) is the Velocity Error.

Note: The Desired Kp, Kv, and Height required to be within 1 Second for the Rise Time, and Less than 5% for the Over Shooting.

and the Code made by the instructor was:

```
function [ u ] = pd_controller(~, s, s_des, params)
% PD_CONTROLLER  PD controller for the height
% s: 2x1 vector containing the current state [z; v_z]
% s_des: 2x1 vector containing desired state [z; v_z]
% params: robot parameters
% FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE
end
```

Finally, The simulator doesn't go so well, and I Couldn't Find the Error

Comment: The code after `% FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE (my Solution)` is yours?

Comment: usually diff of constant are null, you need to have time variant functions for your desired trajectory

Comment: Yes, its mine and I was a little bit confused when I was solving this Cause its my first time, and I don't know how I couldn't Figure Out this Thank you  N. Staub

Comment: The function has s and s_des as inputs, but you always override them. Do you know why is the first input of the function ignored (due to the ~)? Also note that s and s_des is the state vector of the position and its velocity (its first derivative).

Comment: @AmmarTaha please keep your own code so we can point out possible issues

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted *how* you're using your function, which could be problematic, or **what the error is.** That said, even without that information (which **will** be required to get a more detailed answer), there are a few glaring issues. I'll point those out now and request that you *edit your question* to include how you're using the function you provided to perform a simulation, what you were expecting to see in the simulation, and what you actually got, including the *exact errors you got*, if any.

1. You gave a "control equation" of `u = mass*(diff(s_des, 2) + Kpe + Kvdiff(e) + gravity)`. The term `diff(s_des, 2)` doesn't make sense in the context of the question because (a) your `s_des` doesn't have three entries, so you can't take `diff(s_des,2)` (the result is empty), and (b) you're (trying to) use the reference acceleration as a feed-forward term for your controller. This may or may not be in the scope of what you're trying to do, but your question asked specifically about a PD controller. I don't know if you're supposed to have the feed-forward term included.
2. Big Problem #1 - You get the current height and speed, `s`, and then you overwrite it: `s = [0; diff(0)];` You should try just entering that command at the command prompt in Matlab and see what the result is. It's not a 2x1 vector. It certainly is not the current height and speed.
3. Big Problem #2 - Same as Big Problem #1, but for your references `s_des`.
4. Your error term `e` and the derivative error term `diff(e)` suffer from a similar-ish set of problems as the two Big Problems above. You're not using `diff` correctly. Instead of trying to take `diff(e)` to get the *time derivative* of your error, you should instead consider what constitutes your error (hint:position) and what the derivative of a position error would be, and then how you can create that given the current state and reference states you've been given.

Since most of your trouble seems to revolve around `diff` and indexing here's a quick primer on `diff`:

If you have a symbolic expression, then `diff` will give you the symbolic derivative of that expression. You do **not** have a symbolic expression. You have a 2x1 numeric vector.

If you have a numeric vector, then `diff(myVector)` is equivalent to `diff(myVector, 1)`, which is equivalent to `myVector(2:end) - myVector(1:end-1)`. That is, it starts at the second entry in the vector and subtracts from that entry the value in the previous index. It then steps through the entire *remainder* of the vector. If `myVector` is Nx1, then `diff(myVector)` is (N-1)x1.

If you try `diff(myVector, M)`, then Matlab runs the `diff(myVector)` M times and returns that result. Every time it runs the `diff` command your result gets shorter by one. This is why I said earlier that you can't take `diff(s_des, 2)` if `s_des` is only 2 elements big. The starting vector is 2x1, so the result of the first `diff` is (2-1)x1, and the result of the second `diff` is then ((2-1)-1)x1, or 0x1. It's empty.

Further, from a physical meaning perspective, your `s` and `s_des` vectors are [position; speed]. What do you get when you take `diff(s)`? You get [speed - position]. What *physical meaning* does that have? None.

What I would suggest you do (and what I routinely do with all of my code) is to "break out" your inputs as the first thing you do in your code. Since the first entry in `s` is your current position, you might try something like:

```
currentPos = s(1);
```

You can break out the rest of the terms in a similar manner:

```
currentSpeed = s(2);
referencePos = s_des(1);
referenceSpeed = s_des(2);
```

Also important to note is that these terms are **not** a history of values. That is, you can't take `diff(currentPos)` and get a speed. `currentPos` is exactly that - the current position. Nothing more. Again, I would suggest you write the reference error equation and then take the first derivative of that.

Comment: Hi Chuck, I Really do Appreciate Your Desired Effort for Trying to Help me, and I Know that my Problem has many Shits Require Fixing. I am Familiar with mathematics and the Physical Meanings in contrast with Numeric Computations Using MATLAB, so Every thing comes in Conflict. What Matters now is that I do have Feedforward term which don't know how to deal with it. The Simulator Must give me Desired Trajectory of 1 meter Height, <5% Overshooting, and < 1 Second to reach the Height, but it Doesn't Response at all Without Completing the Full Terms of the equation which needs the Feed Term now.